# Macros ($@, $< , $*) in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, macros

I am learning the Makefile Language for Unix.
In the following code:

```
hello: main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $? $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

Alternatively:

hello: main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.cpp $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I am not able to understand what $@ and $@.cpp do? (I don't understand the terms 'dependent files' and 'changed dependent files' ). Also if you could explain what is $< and $* via a simple example, it would be helpful. Thank you.

(Sorry for the many questions - they are slightly related and I didn't want to ask them as separate posts)

Comment: Are you reading the manual?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: Specifically, `$@`, `$<` and `$*` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: @MadScientist I was reading from this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_macros.htm

Comment: In my experience almost every make tutorial out there is marginal at best and downright wrong at worst.  I recommend reading the actual manual.  Most GNU software has pretty good documentation online.